# Quarkus application with extended entitymanager or syncpoints (multiple commits)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, quarkus

I'm writing a Quarkus application that handles very complex requests that need to be committed in stages. Basically (within the same request scope) some initial work needs to be done and the request recorded - then more work, which must be recorded, and more work that must be recorded. Finally the request ends and the final work is committed.

The current solution uses @Transactional methods for the updates. That works. For each method call the changes are saved and committed to the database. The problem is that it is inefficient.

Functionally the JPA entities really live from the start of the request to the end of the request. The same objects are modified slightly during the entire request and with the existing code each change requires a `merge`, which refreshes the entities (or really entity graphs) from the database before applying the updates. Alternatively the changes can use JPA queries with updates, but that is messy and requires a lot of fragile code.

I have tried the Hibernate-specific `update` method as an alternative to `merge`, but while it might work with simple entities it plays havoc with collections (@ElementCollection, @OneToMany). Manual JPA update queries work better.

The ideal approach would be to flush and commit the changes in the transactional methods (no change) but to keep the entity manager open with the entities still attached. Then the entities would live until the request is done. Unfortunately I can't see how that can be done. Extended entity managers are supported with stateful session beans; Quarkus uses CDI.

Is there a way to keep the entity manager open for the whole request and flush and commit several times without resorting to low-level manual code? I would prefer a portable JPA solution, but if I need to use Hibernate-specific code that is acceptable as well.

Comment: Maybe it's not the most beatiful solution but have you considered using user-managed traansactions https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#api-approach ?

Comment: I have, but as far as I can understand it has the same problem. A user-managed transaction can only commit once; after that you need  a new user-managed transaction for the next commit. It is basically the same as calling a @Transactional method (which is probably implemented that way under the hood). If the entity manager cooperates with the user-managed transaction (as it must) it will flush and then presumably detach all entities, just like with a managed transaction.

Comment: You are right, I can only think of using JDBC savepoints as Spring Nested transactions, to keep the session open.